# Does the first piece in a standard blokus game have to have a square on a corner cell?

Tags: blokus

When a player plays his first piece, does it have to cover the corner square? For example, can one play his X piece as first piece?

Comment: I'm not the only Blokus player? :-D Yay!!!

Comment: Standard rules would prohibit playing X first.  If all players agree, you can use any non-standard rules you like, including playing X first or starting away from the corner, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the rues, "The first piece played by each player must cover a corner square." They show an example of an illegal first move, as a piece that "surrounds" the corner without touching it, like an X would. This does mean that the X cannot ever be the first piece.

http://www.mindware.com/Blobs/22021_inst_blokus.pdf

Comment: How can an X be the first piece? Any way you turn it, there's no way you can fit it in a corner.

Comment: I said that it CAN'T ever be the first piece.

Comment: oh, sorry. I misread.

Answer (score 2):

The X is the only piece which cannot be played first.

There is also a smaller (14x14 board) version of the game
for 2 colors, called Duo, or sometimes Travel Blokus,
and the starting point for that is 5 squares in from the
corner on the diagonal.

In that game any piece can be played first, and the X is often chosen.